# Hadoop Authentication http-signature.secret file

Tags: authentication, hadoop, kerberos

I am using hadoop-2.6.0 secured with kerberos authentication. For http authentication there is a property called **hadoop.http.authentication.signature.secret.file**

I have set this property as below in core-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.http.authentication.signature.secret.file</name>
    <value>C:\http-signature.secret</value>
</property>
```

and the **http-signature.secret** file is empty. But http authentication working fine. If i disable this property then i am getting error while starting nodes.

I want to know the usage of this secret file. Why should we set this property? I have googled it but couldn't find the reason.

Help me to understand the usage of this file.

Comment: Hi Mr. kumar, This might be for authenticating purpose. I am not sure in this , I just want to share my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes exactly the same. But what is use of that empty file? How it works? @malli

Comment: While i configure HA(high Availability for Name node) ,i have created empty file named fencing.bat file inside hadoop/bin which is needed when stand by namenode to take over the work of active namenode when active node fail otherwise we get the active node is running eventhough it is fail and also cannot connect fencing.bat. like wise I guess the same for your issue also.

Comment: I could understand the usage of fencing.bat file. But it is totally different i think. In my case, its fully based on security purpose. I hope that there should be a reason for this secret file as well as fencing.bat in HA. I want to find the purpose of this file. How its working internally. Thanks @Malli

Comment: @malli I found an answer and posted. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the below link

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable1/HttpAuthentication.html

[image: Secret File]

Comment: How did you create this file?

Comment: How do we create this secret file?

Comment: You can create it manually and put some text inside that secret file and copy it across all the nodes.